# JavaFX Get preferred size of a Pane

Tags: java, javafx, preferredsize

I need the real preferred size (result from the children) of a Pane but I only get -1. Is there any possibility to find it out?

Ok, here a sample code:
The output is -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0 but obviously the pane with the button has a "preferred" size!? Only the new Thread has as output the "real" size of the pane but not the preferred one because if I resize the window in the 3 seconds it shows the "real" size and not the preferred size of the beginning...

```
public class ButtonTest extends Application
{
    public static void main(String [] a)
    {
        Application.launch(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();


        Button b = new Button("Testbutton");


        pane.getChildren().add(b);
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");

        System.out.println(pane.getPrefWidth());
        System.out.println(pane.getWidth());
        System.out.println(pane.getMinWidth());
        System.out.println(pane.getMaxWidth());

        root.setCenter(pane);
        Scene scene  = new Scene(root);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {           
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO: Handle Exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(pane.getPrefWidth());
                System.out.println(pane.getWidth());
                System.out.println(pane.getMinWidth());
                System.out.println(pane.getMaxWidth());
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code please. Btw, you might get a such result if your pane is empty or not visible or if you did not call the method `setPreferredSize`

Comment: What exactly you mean to preferredsize? If it is -1 it meais any of the class contraints. If you want the actual real size of component, try methods like getBoundsInParent().getWidth().

Answer (score 0):

By default StackPane has the PrefWidth and PrefHeight set by the inherited constraint "USE_COMPUTED_SIZE" (witch values is equal to -1) defined in parent class "Region".

This definition means the preferable size will be computed in layout process.

Perhaps your concept is missplaced. Pref values are used to layout process know how it should arrange object in canvas. To know real size of componente you can use methods like I mentioned before 'getBoundsInParent()' or 'getBoundsInLocal()' (Diference between thoose are explained in javadoc).

BUT is important to understand a component just has his size computed during the layout process. Usually, layout process occurs on separated thread than your events or your main() thread. Thats why after sleeping 3 seconds let you do the trick. You can try something like using the following code to let your code be executed in the JavaFX GUI thread (started on your last line of code):

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        <Your code in GUI Thread>
    }
});
```

Hope it can give a little help. Sorry for not offer you a sample code, but I'm not in a machine with environment installed. Will try to better my answer latter.

Good luck.
(Please anyone, feel free to correct my english, I know it's terrible)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you very much for this explination. But the other methods don't return the right result, too...

Maybe this case helps to understand what my goal is:
One related problem is that I have a SplitPane, two parts, now I hide the second part (divider position = 1.0) and show only the first one, sometimes I like to show also the second part. I do this over repostioning of the dividers. But at any time it can happen, that the second part can be updated with new elements (=> update of the necessary size). Now, to reposition the divider (with an animation) I need the preferred size of the (hidden) second part?! Without real code for that do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Update:
I solved the issue with the "real size" adding a public doubleproperty to the pane and bind it to the widthproperty of the pane. Now I could add a changelistener to this doubleproperty in the splitpane. After first time being visible I got the right pixel size.

```
public DoubleProperty realWidth;

    pane.setPrefWidth(USE_PREF_SIZE);
    pane.setMaxWidth(USE_PREF_SIZE);

    realWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
    realWidth.bind(this.widthProperty());
```

=> Add a change listener from somewhere else

But know I have the problem that if I add a button (after 3 seconds) to the pane the splitpane (the changelistener on this realWidth property) is not notified...

Update: It is notified :D But not adding a button but adding e. g. a stackpane works as expected. Many thanks for your help to understand how it works!